# Posting Google OAuth Developer Verification Form for the private app environment

Tags: google-api, google-signin, google-api-client, google-oauth

I have been trying to make my application verified for quite some time already. The main problem that I have is that my homepage and other pages(except web hooks for push-notifications and oauth2 flow) are private *(because it's dev environment, not prod)* and if you try to access them from the Internet, firewall will not allow you doing so.

Considering what I wrote above, I posted [OAuth Developer Verification Form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification?authuser=2) with the links to my app that aren't accessible for the external network. Now I got the following message from Google:

```
Dear Developer,
Thank you for your patience. Please reply back with a test account email and password, so we can experience the user sign-up flow, validate the app services and then proceed with OAuth Verification process.
Please do not hesitate to reach out to us if you have questions or concerns.
```

Even if I provide the account in my application, Google will not be able to reach the application.

I am sure that there are **thousands** of applications that have DEV/QA and other environments that aren't accessible from the Internet. 
How do you go through verification process?

- How do you go through the process in general?
- What URLs do you specify in the form? Are they private?
- How do you provide user for the Google if you application is not available through the Internet(only web-hooks are available)?

This was so easy for PROD environment, but appears a real nightmare for DEV environments.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but do you even need to have your dev environment verified by Google? What purpose will that do for you? The first line of the link you post states that the verification is for publicly available applications.

Comment: If I don't verify it then after 100 sign ins the application becomes blocked. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509667/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app

Comment: @tehhowch what do you mean?

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509667/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app#comment88526513_50510598 they state, **"We submitted our app for approval and after so much conversation back and forth (which lasted almost 15 days), we got a reply that development/testing apps cannot be approved."**

Comment: Yes, I've read that. That's frustrating but seems there should be a workaround. Because, if it's true then the whole interactions with google api becomes nightmare.  There are thousands of applications that use Oauth flow. They couldn't have harmed that much for everyone by just removing possibility to have dev/qa env.