# Gmailr Disabled Gmail Connection Access

Tags: r, gmailr

I created a shiny app that allows me to connect to my gmail using the gmailr app. I've had it running for a few months now and then all of a sudden Google disabled access. How to I get access back?

[image]

gmailr::gmail_auth()

Comment: You may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509667/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app0

Comment: thanks, taking a look now @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow instructions [here](https://github.com/r-lib/gmailr/issues/111#issuecomment-520409086)

Creating a project in Google Developers Console and providing Credentials from project fixed a problem for me.