# R Googlsheets: Unable to use `gs_auth()` in googlesheets package - Sign In With Google Temporarily Disabled App Not Verified Issue

Tags: r, google-oauth, tidyverse, google-signin, google-authentication

I am unable to authenticate my googlesheets package. Everytime I run the `gs_auth()` command I am taken to the chrome where I would usually login to enable the package to access my googlesheets:

[image]

However, lately every time I do this I have the following error from Google:

[image]

Here my session information:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=C              LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] googlesheets_0.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2        crayon_1.3.4      dplyr_0.8.3       withr_2.1.2       assertthat_0.2.1  cellranger_1.1.0  R6_2.4.0         
 [8] magrittr_1.5      httr_1.4.1        pillar_1.4.2      rlang_0.4.1       cli_1.1.0         curl_4.2          renv_0.8.2-12    
[15] rstudioapi_0.10   tools_3.6.1       glue_1.3.1        purrr_0.3.3       compiler_3.6.1    askpass_1.1       pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[22] sessioninfo_1.1.1 openssl_1.4.1     tidyselect_0.2.5  tibble_2.1.3     

gs_auth()
```

I have also followed the instructions given here [on this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509667/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app). However still no luck.

I have been able to access my sheet using the `googledrive` package, however I'd still like to fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

googlesheets4 will replace googlesheets package [very soon](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets) (by March 2020). Most of the functions performed by googlesheets can be handled by googlesheets4 currently, except for writing to specific cells.

googlesheets4 has a oauth authentication using Gargle (similar to googledrive package). More info can be found here - https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4

Comment: Does this mean we can't use the original `googlesheets` package?

Comment: Googlesheets4 is an absolute mess for Shiny apps. Authentication is a real problem and I haven't been able to solve it yet.

Comment: @Diya if you do find a solution for using googlesheets4 with Shiny, could you please let me know? I've been trying for hours here. It's a real problem

Comment: @Diya I managed to use it for a bunch of apps deployed on `shinyapps.io`. What issue are you facing? You can use the `token` rather than trying to authenticate from the broswer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the answer from Jenny Bryan (maintainer of `googlesheets` and `googlesheets4`) from Github to this issue here:

"Default oauth app not working any more"
https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/issues/397

The link includes pretty detailed, step-by-step instructions, and I won't repeat what's she's already laid out really well. But quick version is you'll need to set up your own API credentials to make the oAuth client work. And remember, that will only help until March 2020.

Probably better, as @Kannan and others point out, is to make the switch to the new `googlesheets4` package now if you can.