# R Studio - package googlesheets does not work anymore

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-signin

Hi I want to use the package "googlesheets" in R but when i try to authenticate than i get the error message from google:

> "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for 
>             this app
>              This app has not yet been verified by Google in order 
>        to use Google Sign in."

Does anybody know, how can i fix that?

Comment: https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/issues/397

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58869050/r-googlsheets-unable-to-use-gs-auth-in-googlesheets-package-sign-in-with