# How do you proceed when "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app"?

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-signin

I am trying to use the `googlesheets` package in R, but whenever I am prompted to sign into my Google account following `gs_ls()` or `gs_auth()` commands I receive an error saying "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app; This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In." How do I proceed from here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the rules of a 3rd party software application.

Comment: That package [is being deprecated](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets). Look at [googlesheets4](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/) instead.

Comment: Same thing was asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58923872/5325862

Answer (score 1):

Try [googlesheets4](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/) BUT 4 **does not yet have write capabilities (as of 11/24/19**. [Make your own Oauth client](https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/get-api-credentials.html) (easy) in the meantime.

The developer [is working on write capabilities in v4](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/issues/397). This occurred because Google has been cracking down on insecure or easily abused use of their API. Or more likely because they want to nudge people to start using the new version of the Google API.

Quoting the developer, jennybc:

> I am quoting heavily from / linking to the page I linked to above.
>
> Step 1: Get a Google Cloud Platform Project:
>
> https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/get-api-credentials.html#get-a-google-cloud-platform-project
>
> Step 2: Enable APIs
>
> https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/get-api-credentials.html#enable-apis
>
> To make googlesheets (this package work), enable Drive and Sheets.
>
> Step 3: Get an OAuth app = client ID and secret
>
> https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/get-api-credentials.html#oauth-client-id-and-secret

Comment: why do people want to aggressively close a question? Why is that the fact that package is going to be deprecated anything to do with answering the question? It is still live and in use.

Comment: I don't know. I ask myself the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Today's status is that while googlesheets4 is allowing to **read** a googlesheet, or check the files using `gs4_find()` the earlier success we had in `googledrive::drive_upload()` or `googlesheets::gs_upload()` fail now. The former just doesn't do anything while the latter takes you to a authentication page through the browser and then the infamous message

> "Sign in disabled with Google temporarily disabled for this app "

I have copied the API key json file and used all guidelines regarding use of API key. No luck with upload.