# R can't access googlesheets4, despite API enabled

Tags: r, googlesheets4

I use R to connect to Google Analytics and I can sign in, but when trying to connect to Google Sheets it doesn't let me sign in. I tried the following code:

```
library(googlesheets4)
gs_auth()
```

And it takes me to the user authentication page, but the message is again:

> Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
>   This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

I checked that googlesheets API is enabled. Do you have any advice for this issue? Thank you.

Regards,

Alexis

Comment: Try following this guide: https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/drive-and-sheets.html. Otherwise tell us exactly what steps you followed to enable the API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Googlsheets: Unable to use \`gs\_auth()\` in googlesheets package - Sign In With Google Temporarily Disabled App Not Verified Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58869050/r-googlsheets-unable-to-use-gs-auth-in-googlesheets-package-sign-in-with)

Comment: Hello @MrFlick and camille, I have solved this problem, the wrong part of the code was using gs_auth(), which is not recognized by the googlesheets4 library. I had to use sheets_auth() which authenticates and grants access to google sheets. Thank you very much for being patient and give me your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use sheets_auth() which authenticates and grants access in googlesheets4 library.