# Error message when when trying to connect Google Sheets to GA API

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

I'm new to scripts & coding and need help. I need to connect my Google Sheet to Google Analytics API.

I have the script in the Script Editor and when I run it, I get a message that it needs permission to access the data in Google.

When I enter my login credentials I get an error message that says "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app" "This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In."

I'm already logged in with Google sheets...what does this mean and how do I get around it? Thank you.

Comment: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en this should give an idea. But show some effort first like what you tried what happened etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509667/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app)