# Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app: This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting this error when trying to authorize a brand new Apps Script to run on my Gmail account:

Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

Note that I wrote the script myself, so it should be trusted.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509667/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to run simple Google Script: Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070450/trying-to-run-simple-google-script-sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for)