# Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app - Google OAuth

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-developers-console

We are working on a Django app, in which we are using Gmail API's services `(Restricted SCOPE)`.

As our app is still under construction so we didn't submit it for verification on the google cloud form. **The app that we are trying to authenticate is used for internal development and we did not publish it to our users.**

So we are facing "[This app is not verified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH6sg.png)" screen and fortunately, we can log in after skipping this screen by clicking on the Advance option. We tried it with our personal and test accounts it works well.

But whenever our client trying to authenticate Gmail with the app he is facing this issue. ["Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRsHl.png).

**We checked we did not reach the limit of 100 users accessing the application.**

Is this because of the location issue? or our client is using some kind of Anti Virus or any other extra security checkup? What issue it can be? can someone please help?

Comment: Have you checked with [Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) to see what is going on?

Comment: @Kessy we didn't have Google Workspace Support :(

Comment: Have you checked the answer form [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509667/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app)? Also, you could publish your app and set it as unlisted so only the ones with the marketplace link can install it and you can list it whenever is ready

Answer (score 0):

> "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app".

Once you have reached this point you have used up your quota of users who can sign into your application.  As you mention the limit is 100 users who have authenticated your application.

What counts as a user has been debated for a long time.

If a developer authenticates your app then revokes their access then authenticates again this in my experience is probably counted as two against your quota.

So its not really number of unique users, but number of users who have seen an consented to the consent screen.

As you have now reached this limit your only option is to

- wait for verification
- create a new project on developer console and start the verification process again but with a new 100 users

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we can see the number of registered in the console tab are only 22 as well as we tried with another test account, it works like a cham but the issue is at our client end. he can't authenticate his personal account and facing the mentioned issue.

Comment: What console tab?  As far as i know there is no way of seeing what users have authorized an application.

Comment: @DalmTo [Check here](https://i.imgur.com/0fO7QCV.png) we can see the remaining users here.

Comment: Can you double check its the same project.  In the mean time i am going to ping someone at Google to find out how accurate that screen is.  Just to be on the safe side.  (I can not guarantee that 1. i will hear back from google at all. or 2. hear back this side of the new year)

Comment: As i feared everyone at Google that i now of to ask is on vacation. Will have to wait until the new year to get any response from them.

Comment: yeah we have to wait until new year :)

Comment: @DalmTo Any update on this? also how can we contact the Google cloud console team?

Comment: Nope not a peep.

Answer (score -2):

You should setup for Oauth consent screen.

[image]

You can setup Oauth consent screen for oauth authenticate through "navigation -> APIs&Services -> Oauth consent screen".

[image]

Then you need to fill in required informations below.

> 1. Your app logo (if applicable)
> 2. Your app name, which will be a dynamic link to give users your app's support email  address
> 3. The data you are requesting, or scopes, which you will add in the next step
> 4. Links to your app's privacy policy and terms of service

After you fill in domain,links..etc properly, You can use oauth authentication on your app.

Comment: As I said, this app is not published for the user, this app is still under construction. so before going for verification we want it to be worked it for our client as it works on our side.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether your app is published or not. You should setup consent screen for authenticating via Oauth 2.0. Still have problem? Then try to submit domain verification process from "Domain verification" pannel under the "Oauth consent screen"

Comment: @kallusis369 this is not related to the error message they are getting.